# How to set GPIO falling edge interrupt in linux

Tags: linux, interrupt, gpio

I try to use GPIO Interrut(falling edge) in linux (using GPIO Expander PCAL6524).

At first I set GPIO low_active/direction like the following.

```
static int pcal6524_setup(struct i2c_client *client, int gpio,
                unsigned int ngpio, void *context)
{
    int status;
    unsigned char i;
    char label[15];

    gpio += INPUT_BASE;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        snprintf(label, 10, "exp_input%d", i);
        status = gpio_request(gpio, label);
        if (status)
            goto out_free;
        exp_gpio[i] = gpio++;

        status = gpio_direction_input(exp_gpio[i]);
        if (status) {
            gpio_free(exp_gpio[i]);
            exp_gpio[i] = -EINVAL;
            goto out_free;
        }

        status = gpio_export(exp_gpio[i], 1);
        if (status) {
            gpio_free(exp_gpio[i]);
            exp_gpio[i] = -EINVAL;
            goto out_free;
        }

        status = gpio_sysfs_set_active_low(exp_gpio[i], 1);
        if (status < 0) {
            gpio_free(exp_gpio[i]);
            exp_gpio[i] = -EINVAL;
            goto out_free;
        }
    }

    return status;

out_free:
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        if (exp_gpio[i] != -EINVAL) {
            gpio_free(exp_gpio[i]);
            exp_gpio[i] = -EINVAL;
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

I checked whether GPIOs set to right at "/sys/class/gpio/gpioN" 
- active_low : 1, direction : in

But now I don't know how to set GPIO falling edge.
I try to set GPIO falling edge in JNI like the following.
But the open error was occurred.(/sys/class/gpio/gpioN/edge)

```
/****************************************************************
 * gpio_set_edge
 ****************************************************************/
#define GPIO_PATH "/sys/class/gpio"

int gpio_set_edge(unsigned int gpio, char *edge)
{
    int fd, len;
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    len = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), GPIO_PATH "/gpio%d/edge", gpio);

    fd = open(buf, O_WRONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("gpio/set-edge");
        return fd;
    }

    write(fd, edge, strlen(edge) + 1); 
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the main routine to check and proceed the GPIO Falling edge interrupt.

```
/****************************************************************
 * Main
 ****************************************************************/
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    struct pollfd fdset[2];
    int nfds = 2;
    int gpio_fd, timeout, rc;
    char *buf[MAX_BUF];
    unsigned int gpio;
    int len;



    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: gpio-int <gpio-pin>\n\n");
        printf("Waits for a change in the GPIO pin voltage level or input on stdin\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    gpio = atoi(argv[1]);

    gpio_set_edge(gpio, "rising");
    gpio_fd = gpio_fd_open(gpio);

    timeout = POLL_TIMEOUT;

    while (1) {
        memset((void*)fdset, 0, sizeof(fdset));

        fdset[0].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
        fdset[0].events = POLLIN;

        fdset[1].fd = gpio_fd;
        fdset[1].events = POLLPRI;

        rc = poll(fdset, nfds, timeout);      

        if (rc < 0) {
            printf("\npoll() failed!\n");
            return -1;
        }

        if (rc == 0) {
            printf(".");
        }

        if (fdset[1].revents & POLLPRI) {
            lseek(fdset[1].fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
            len = read(fdset[1].fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
            printf("\npoll() GPIO %d interrupt occurred\n", gpio);
        }

        if (fdset[0].revents & POLLIN) {
            (void)read(fdset[0].fd, buf, 1);
            printf("\npoll() stdin read 0x%2.2X\n", (unsigned int) buf[0]);
        }

        fflush(stdout);
    }

    gpio_fd_close(gpio_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I found why the open error was occurred..
When I checked the file property of gpio, I found that the read/write permission of gpio is the following.

> 130|shell@test_ref:/sys/class/gpio/gpio218 $ ll
>   -rw-r--r-- root     root         4096 2009-09-01 01:56 active_low
>
> lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2009-09-01 01:56 device ->
>   ../../../0-0022
>
> -rw-r--r-- root     root         4096 2009-09-01 01:56 direction
>
> -rw-r--r-- root     root         4096 2009-09-01 00:30 edge
>
> drwxr-xr-x root     root              2009-09-01 00:00 power
>
> lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2009-09-01 01:56 subsystem ->
>   ../../../../../../../class/gpio
>
> -rw-r--r-- root     root         4096 2009-09-01 00:00 uevent
>
> -rw-r--r-- root     root         4096 2009-09-01 00:00 value

As above, the write permission of gpio/edge has been denied...

How can I permit the write authority of gpio/edge, in the linux kernel?

Comment: I have resolved this problem.  I add the following in init.rc    
    write /sys/class/gpio/export "218"
    write /sys/class/gpio/gpio218/active_low "1"
    write /sys/class/gpio/gpio218/direction "in"
    write /sys/class/gpio/gpio218/edge "falling"